# JEDEC device health report

Tags: android, monitoring, hardware

We're building an Android device that uses e.MMC flash memory. We have bad experiences with flash memory quality, so I have defined a long term test with thousands of write cycles.

Now I became aware of the JEDEC device health report, which seems to be built-in in all JEDEC compatible flash memory. During our long-term test, I'd like to monitor those values in regular intervals.

Requirements:

- command line tool or app
- runs on Android 5.0
- generates a JEDEC device health report
- ideally can save reports into a file so it needs no user interaction

At the moment I don't care about the cost.